# Variable rule in dependent type theory

Tags: type-theory, dependent-types

This is the = Type variable rule that I'm seeing through out the my course and unable to grasp it completely.

$$\dfrac{\phi \vdash \Gamma[\mathrm{ctx}] \qquad \Gamma(x) = \tau}
        {\phi; \Gamma \vdash x : \tau}
        \textsf{(ty-var)}$$

The first thing in antecedent looks like it's stating that $\Gamma$ is well-formed under the context $\phi$, is that right? What does the second thing in antecedent mean? I have a feeling of this but I am unable to get this simple rule.

Comment: What's $\phi$ here?

Comment: Actually that was from ML0,pi (C) so that's called "sort type" or type of the constraint domain where type index objects are drawn.

Comment: i'm new to type theory and have verification(Model checking) background. So it's really new thing to me. I'm reading paper "Dependent Types in practical programming".

Comment: Please ask your follow-up question as a separate question. It's a completely different issue. (An interesting one, too, so I do encourage you to ask it, but please ask one question at a time.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, $\Gamma$ is a store that maps variables to types.

This rule says that we can deduce that a variable has a type in a context if that type is stored for our variable in the context.

The rule is deliberately simple, and is a base case for the inductive process that is type derivation.

In short, to check the type of a variable, just look it up in the environment.

Comment: Thanks . Any references where i could get all explanation as clear as you have stated for other rules ?

Comment: Maybe Types and Programming Languages by Pierce? I'm not sure, as a rule it's not exclusive to depenent types, it's in basically every type system. So I don't have a particular reference off hand, but any introduction to type theory should have it.

Comment: @Pushpa, jmite: Dependent types are in the second volume [ATTAPL](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/attapl/) (both good books by the way). While the basic principle is common to most type systems, dependent types does make the formuation more complex (an introduction to type theory would just have $\dfrac{\Gamma(x)=\tau}{\Gamma \vdash x:\tau}$ because that's all you need with simple types).